# Is there a rapid way to sort tables using VBA macro code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this sheet with around 1 mil rows and 3 tables that have the same header (10 columns cells) and data in the next 10 columns and are unsorted. The ideea is that I want a VBA macro code to copy the 1 table in a new workbook sheet and for the other 2 tables to be sorted. I tried suing a if statement but excel stops responding. Can anyone give me a hand for this?

Src

```
   H1...H10 V1...V10 | H1...H10 V1...V10 | H1...H10 V1...V10
    x....x  1.....x  |  z....z  1.....z  |  k....k  1.....k
    y....y  1.....y  |  k....k  1.....k  |  z....z  1.....z
    k....k  1.....k  |  y....y  1.....y  |  x....x  1.....x
    z....z  1.....z  |  x....x  1.....x  |  y....y  1.....y
```

Dest

```
    H1...H10 V1...V10 | V1...V10  |  V1...V10
     x....x  1.....x  |  1.....x  |  1.....x
     y....y  1.....y  |  1.....y  |  1.....y
     k....k  1.....k  |  1.....k  |  1.....k
     z....z  1.....z  |  1.....z  |  1.....z
```

My loop part of the code is like this:

```
        k = Dest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Dest.Range(Dest.Cells(2, 1), Dest.Cells(k, 62)).Clear
        n = Src.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
          For i = 2 To Src.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                  Dest.Range(Dest.Cells(a, 1), Dest.Cells(a, 20)).Value = 
                        Src.Range(Src.Cells(i, 1), Src.Cells(i, 20)).Value
          Next i

          For i = 2 To Src.Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
              For j = 2 To Dest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                 If Src.Cells(i, 22).Value = Dest.Cells(j, 1).Value And _
                    Src.Cells(i, 24).Value = Dest.Cells(j, 3).Value And _
                    Src.Cells(i, 25).Value = Dest.Cells(j, 4).Value And _
                    Src.Cells(i, 26).Value = Dest.Cells(j, 5).Value Then
                    Dest.Range(Dest.Cells(j, 22), Dest.Cells(j, 35)).Value = Src.Range(Src.Cells(i, 28), Src.Cells(i, 41)).Value
                 End If

              Next j
          Next i

          For i = 2 To Src.Range("AQ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           For j = 2 To Dest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
               If Src.Cells(i, 43).Value = Dest.Cells(j, 1).Value And _
                  Src.Cells(i, 45).Value = Dest.Cells(j, 3).Value And _
                  Src.Cells(i, 46).Value = Dest.Cells(j, 4).Value And _
                  Src.Cells(i, 47).Value = Dest.Cells(j, 5).Value Then
                     Dest.Range(Dest.Cells(j, 37), Dest.Cells(j, 50)).Value = Src.Range(Src.Cells(i, 49), Src.Cells(i, 62)).Value
            End If
          Next  j
         Next i
```

Comment: What is your VBA Code look like? Try adding `DoEvents` statement inside your loop. It will cause the VBA code to NOT freeze up EXCEL and will let you see what is going on, and also give you a chance to stop the application if you choose to do so./

Comment: Loading you data to Power Query would be able to better handle large data sets like this.

Comment: (1)  The first section of your code gives a syntax error because there is no line continuation character at the end of the fifth line.  If you fix that error, the code does not work because you have not initialised `a` to 2 and do not step it within the loop.  Unless these are transcription errors, I do not believe you have tried to run this code.

Comment: (2)  You are looking for matches between table 2 and table 1 and then between table 3 and table 1 in the most inefficient manner.  You do not even stop the search for a match if you find one.

Comment: (3)  You match columns H1, H3, H4 and H5 of tables 2 and 3 against the same columns in table 1.  You do not check columns H2 and H6 to H10 so the output would be misleading if these differed.

Comment: (4)  In you example data, you have the same H columns in all three tables but in a different sequence.  With the real data, would you expect exactly the same H column in all three tables?  If there was a row in table 2 or table 3 that was missing from table 1, that row would not be in the output.  Is this correct?

Comment: The H1 to H10 are headers that are the same in all 3 tables. The main table is a total lets say. If some values do not exist in table 2 they exist for sure in table 3.  I ran the code but excel freezes but the data until then is copied correctly.

Comment: The row should be in the out put but with no data from the table 2 or table 3

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in providing the answer I promised.  I have not had the spare time I expected and your problem is more difficult than I expected.  I have a first solution which I will post today.  I believe your code would have taken weeks or months to merge three tables of one million rows.  My first solution took 47 minutes to merge three tables of ten thousand rows which suggests one million rows would take three and a bit days.  I have some ideas for reducing this duration but I will post the current code before testing those ideas.

Comment: Please try my solution.  Start with a few rows from your million row worksheet and then try more and more rows until the duration becomes too excessive to be sensible.  I have tested my code with data I have generated that matches my understanding of your worksheet.  My concern is that my data does not match yours and my code will require extensive modification before it will work with your data.  If so I would appreciate knowing sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my Answer 3.  My code was faster than yours but was it fast enough to be useful?  If not, do you want to consider VB?  A VB solution would be very, substantially faster than a VBA solution.  I can show you how to convert my VBA code to VB.

Comment: If you reply to my last comment please include @ followed by my name so the system tells me you have replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 3**

My attempt to create VBA code that is faster than that in Answer 2 has failed.  The problem is:

```
With WshtSrc
  SrcCellValues = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast)).Value
End With
```

Downloading an entire worksheet to memory can speed up code that accesses the cells within the worksheet.  The above code worked correctly at first but as my workbook got bigger with more code and more worksheets, I got “out of memory” errors.  I had to stop downloading the worksheet.  Accessing the cells directly slowed my code enough to cancel the speed improvements achieved with better techniques.

With optimistic assumptions, your original code would have taken well over one hundred days.  I have reduced this to a little over 3 days.  If this is a one-off task, you could leave your computer running over a long weekend.  If this is a regular task, I do not believe Excel VBA is viable.

You should not be holding this volume of data in Excel; you should use a database.  I think even Access would be better.  An Access macro which output the destination worksheet to a new workbook would give the appearance you seek and, because there is so much less processing, it should give acceptable performance.

If you must use Excel to hold the data, I suggest VB.  VB is the replacement for VBA.  The VB syntax is similar to VBA so the learning curve is not too steep.  The Community version (which would be adequate for your needs) is free.  People will tell you that VB access to or from Excel is slow which is true.  Each individual access is slow but I expect a VB program would download the entire source worksheet and upload the destination worksheet in seconds.  Between the download and the upload, VB processing is much, much faster than VBA processing.  I had a client who was attempting a complicated calculation in VBA.  Extrapolating up from a small part of the calculation, I estimated the total duration as 43 days.  By porting the code to VB, I go the duration down to 52 minutes.  VB will almost certainly offer a viable solution so you should consider it if a database is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**

As I said in my comment, the code in your question contains errors that prevent it working.  Consider:

```
Dest.Range(Dest.Cells(a, 1), Dest.Cells(a, 20)).Value = 
           Src.Range(Src.Cells(i, 1), Src.Cells(i, 20)).Value
```

These lines give a syntax error because there is no continuation line character at the end of the first line.  You need:

```
Dest.Range(Dest.Cells(a, 1), Dest.Cells(a, 20)).Value = _
           Src.Range(Src.Cells(i, 1), Src.Cells(i, 20)).Value
```

Consider:

```
For i = 2 To Src.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Dest.Range(Dest.Cells(a, 1), Dest.Cells(a, 20)).Value = _
                    Src.Range(Src.Cells(i, 1), Src.Cells(i, 20)).Value
 Next i
```

`a` is not initialised in the code you posted.  If you run this code, you get “Application-defined or object-defined error” because the default value for `a` is zero and there is no row 0.  If `a = 2` is added, every row of the source table 1 is copied to row 2 of the destination worksheet because `a` is not stepped within the loop.  If you add `a = a + 1` within the loop, the code works but is slow.

Timing VBA routines is tricky because of the number of background activities that can fire at any time.  My timings with 10,000 and 30,000 rows suggest this copy runs at about .15 seconds per 1,000 rows giving about 150 seconds for a million rows.  Adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` reduces the runtime but only by a little.

Instead of copying row by row, it is possible to copy the entire block in one go.  You are using `Range.Value = Range.Value` for each row.  You could have enlarged the ranges to cover the entire block.  I prefer `Range.Copy Destination:=Cell` since only the range to be copied needs to be fully specified.  With this change, the runtime reduces to about 25 seconds for a million rows.

My code at this stage is below.  There are a number of important differences from your code.

There are no variable names like: `k`, `n`, `i`, `a` and so on in my code.  It is possible to remember what such variables are while you are writing the code but will you remember when you return to this code in six or twelve months?  Worse, you are asking others to review your code to whom these names are meaningless.  I have a system of naming variables which I will explain if it is not obvious from my code.  You may not like my system.  This is fine, make up your own in consultation with your colleagues.  I can look at code my colleagues and I wrote years ago and know what all the variables are.  My names are much longer that yours but the extra effort of typing my names is repaid by every statement being so much easier to understand.

I do not include literals like 1 and 20 for column numbers.  I have seen too many worksheets change over time.  An extra column here, columns swapped there and so on.  Looking through code trying to decide which literals are column numbers to be changed and which serve some other purpose is a nightmare.  Using names like `ColTbl1Start` and `ColTbl1End` would make it easy to update the code if the tables ever moved or changed their size.  They also make the code easier to read; what are 20, 22 and “AV”?

I do not clear the used rows in worksheet Destination; I delete every row in the worksheet which is much easier.

You use `End(xlUp)` to find the last used row in a column.  This is the easiest way of finding the last used row when you are confident that a particular column has a value in every row.  If no such column exists you have a problem because although there are several techniques for finding the last row or column, no one technique works in every case.  Some years ago I decided to write a routine that always found the last row and column of a worksheet.  I have included `FindLastRowCol` in my code.

```
Option Explicit

  Const ColTbl1Start As Long = 1
  Const ColTbl1End As Long = 20

Sub Test()

  Dim a As Long
  Dim ColSrcLast As Long
  Dim Dest As Worksheet
  Dim I As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long
  Dim Src As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set Src = Worksheets("Source")
  Set Dest = Worksheets("Destination")

  Dest.Cells.EntireRow.Delete

  Call FindLastRowCol(Src, RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast)

  With Src
    .Range(.Cells(1, ColTbl1Start), .Cells(RowSrcLast, ColTbl1End)).Copy Destination:=Dest.Cells(1, 1)
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Public Sub FindLastRowCol(ByRef Wsht As Worksheet, ByRef RowLast As Long, _
                          ByRef ColLast As Long)

  ' Sets RowLast and ColLast to the last row and column with a value
  ' in worksheet Wsht

  ' The motivation for coding this routine was the discovery that Find by
  ' previous row found a cell formatted as Merge and Center but Find by
  ' previous column did not. I had known that Find would miss merged
  ' cells but this was new to me.

  '   Dec16  Coded
  ' 31Dec16  Corrected handling of UserRange
  ' 15Feb17  SpecialCells was giving a higher row number than Find for
  '          no reason I could determine.  Added code to check for a
  '          value on rows and columns above those returned by Find
  ' 25Jun17  Found column with value above that found by Find. Fixed.

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLastFind As Long
  Dim ColLastOther As Long
  Dim ColLastTemp As Long
  Dim ColLeft As Long
  Dim ColRight As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowIncludesMerged As Boolean
  Dim RowBot As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLastFind As Long
  Dim RowLastOther As Long
  Dim RowLastTemp As Long
  Dim RowTop As Long

  With Wsht

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastFind = 0
      ColLastFind = 0
    Else
      RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      ColLastFind = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Else
      If RowLastFind < Rng.Row Then
        RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      End If
      If ColLastFind < Rng.Column Then
        ColLastFind = Rng.Column
      End If
    End If

    Set Rng = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastOther = 0
      ColLastOther = 0
    Else
      RowLastOther = Rng.Row
      ColLastOther = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .UsedRange
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Else
      If RowLastOther < Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        RowLastOther = Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
      End If
      If ColLastOther < Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1 Then
        ColLastOther = Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
      End If
    End If

    If RowLastFind < RowLastOther Then
      ' Higher row found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While RowLastOther > RowLastFind
        ColLastTemp = .Cells(RowLastOther, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If ColLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(RowLastOther, 1).Value <> "" Then
          Debug.Assert False
          ' Is this possible
          ' Row after RowLastFind has value
          RowLastFind = RowLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        RowLastOther = RowLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf RowLastFind > RowLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    RowLast = RowLastFind

    If ColLastFind < ColLastOther Then
      ' Higher column found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While ColLastOther > ColLastFind
        RowLastTemp = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColLastOther).End(xlUp).Row
        If RowLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(1, ColLastOther).Value <> "" Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          ' Column after ColLastFind has value
          ' Possible causes:
          '   * Find does not recognise merged cells
          '   ' Find does not examine hidden cells
          ColLastFind = ColLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        ColLastOther = ColLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf ColLastFind > ColLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    ColLast = ColLastFind

  End With

End Sub
```

The above code only replaces the first section of your code.  It copies table 1 from worksheet Source to worksheet Destination.

Your code to merge in tables 2 and 3 would be incredibly slow.  My guess is that it would take days to merge in tables containing a million rows.  I can suggest minor improvements but really you need a totally different approach.

I have a number of ideas which I will try.  I aim to post the rest of my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Tony and thanks for your update.  You`re right that my code is king of nonsense and sloppy. The thing is that the final result should look like a vlookup think. I want to copy the 1 table that is done very fast, and after that knowing that all 3 tables has the same 1 row headers and the 10 columns headers, i only wanted to check if the range 1 to 10 for every row in the 1 table exists in the next 2 tables, if yes copy the next 10 cell range. something like that.

Comment: @DanielC  I have been busy with family matters and have not had time to complete the promised routine.  Sorry.  The parts I have completed suggest the total duration to merge three tables of a million rows will be less than 30 minutes.  However, I am concerned at the size of the workbook. I have generated a workbook with three million row tables and it is 355 Mbytes.  The destination workbook will be smaller since there is only one copy of the H columns but this is still enormous.  My cells contain 8 and 9 character strings.  Are your a lot smaller or is your workbook as big.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 2, Part 2**

I told you in my first answer that I do not like literals in my code.  I do not want to reference row number 2 as the first data row because there is one header row.  I do not want to reference column 5 as a column number because that is currently the date column.  Partly this is because rows and column move and looking through code trying to decide which 2s and 5s are row and column numbers is a nightmare.  But mainly it is because I think it makes the code easier to read.  In my earlier answer I used constants such as `RowSrcDataFirst` or `ColDate`.  I have used some constants with my new code but I want arrays so I can access table properties as `Property(InxTable)`.  There are no array constants so I have a routine to initialise these arrays.  The constants and the routine are in module “ModGlobal”:

```
Option Explicit

  ' Colours for the V tables within destination worksheet
  Public ClrVTbls() As Variant

  ' Start and end columns for tables within destination worksheet
  ' There is one H table and then one V table per table in source worksheet
  ' These arrays are Long because there values are calculated
  Public ColDestHTblEnd As Long
  Public ColDestHTblStart As Long
  Public ColDestVTblsEnd() As Long
  Public ColDestVTblsStart() As Long

  ' Start and end columns for tables within source worksheet
  ' Each table has 10 H columns followed by 10 V columns
  ' These arrays are Variant because they are loaded using VBA.Array
  Public ColSrcTblsEnd() As Variant
  Public ColSrcTblsStart() As Variant
  Public ColSrcHTblsEnd() As Variant
  Public ColSrcHTblsStart() As Variant
  Public ColSrcVTblsEnd() As Variant
  Public ColSrcVTblsStart() As Variant

  Public Const InxTblMax As Long = 2     ' The tables are numbered zero to InxTblMax

  Public Const RowDestDataFirst As Long = 3
  Public Const RowSrcDataFirst As Long = 2

  Public Const WshtDestName As String = "Destination"
  Public Const WshtSrcName As String = "Source"

Sub LoadTblVariables()

  ' Load the global variables used to access the tables and the columns
  ' within them.

  ' The tables all have the same format and all require the same processing.
  ' Recording the start and end columns in arrays the same code can be used
  ' for all tables.

  ' If the tables ever change size or are moved, this routine MUST be changed
  ' to match.

  ' The arrays are loaded using VBA.Array which always sets the lower bound
  ' to zero.  In the code, The tables are numbered zero upwards to match the
  ' arrays.

  Dim InxTblCrnt As Long

  ' Load column numbers for tables within source worksheet
  ColSrcTblsStart = VBA.Array(1, 22, 43)    ' Start of each table
  ColSrcTblsEnd = VBA.Array(20, 41, 62)     ' End of each table
  ColSrcHTblsStart = VBA.Array(1, 22, 43)   ' Start of H columns for each table
  ColSrcHTblsEnd = VBA.Array(10, 31, 52)    ' End of H columns for each table
  ColSrcVTblsStart = VBA.Array(11, 32, 53)  ' Start of V columns for each table
  ColSrcVTblsEnd = VBA.Array(20, 41, 62)    ' End of V columns for each table

  ' If execution stops on one of these statements, the number of H columns is
  ' not the same in each table
  For InxTblCrnt = 1 To InxTblMax
  Debug.Assert ColSrcHTblsEnd(0) - ColSrcHTblsStart(0) = _
               ColSrcHTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt) - ColSrcHTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)
  Next

  ' Record position of H table within destination worksheet
  ColDestHTblStart = 1
  ColDestHTblEnd = ColDestHTblStart + ColSrcHTblsEnd(0) - ColSrcHTblsStart(0)

  ' Record position of V tables within destination worksheet
  ' Note that the code does not require the V tables be the same width
  ReDim ColDestVTblsStart(0 To InxTblMax)
  ReDim ColDestVTblsEnd(0 To InxTblMax)
  ColDestVTblsStart(0) = ColDestHTblEnd + 1
  ColDestVTblsEnd(0) = ColDestVTblsStart(0) + ColSrcVTblsEnd(0) - ColSrcVTblsStart(0)
  For InxTblCrnt = 1 To InxTblMax
    ColDestVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt) = ColDestVTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt - 1) + 1
    ColDestVTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt) = ColDestVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt) + _
                                  ColSrcVTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt) - _
                                  ColSrcVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)
  Next

  ' Record colours for V tables within destination worksheet
  ClrVTbls = VBA.Array(RGB(226, 239, 218), RGB(255, 242, 204), RGB(221, 235, 247))

  'Debug.Print "Tables in source worksheet:"
  'For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
  '  Debug.Print "  Table " & InxTblCrnt + 1 & ": " & _
  '              ColNumToCode(ColSrcTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)) & " to " & _
  '              ColNumToCode(ColSrcTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt))
  'Next
  'Debug.Print "H Columns in source worksheet:"
  'For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
  '  Debug.Print "  Table " & InxTblCrnt + 1 & ": " & _
  '              ColNumToCode(ColSrcHTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)) & " to " & _
  '              ColNumToCode(ColSrcHTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt))
  'Next
  'Debug.Print "V Columns in source worksheet:"
  'For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
  '  Debug.Print "  Table " & InxTblCrnt + 1 & ": " & _
  '              ColNumToCode(ColSrcVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)) & " to " & _
  '              ColNumToCode(ColSrcVTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt))
  'Next
  'Debug.Print "H Table in destination worksheet:"
  'Debug.Print "  " & ColNumToCode(ColDestHTblStart) & " to " & _
  '                   ColNumToCode(ColDestHTblEnd)
  'Debug.Print "V Tables in destination worksheet:"
  'For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
  '  Debug.Print "  Table " & InxTblCrnt + 1 & ": " & _
  '              ColNumToCode(ColDestVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)) & " to " & _
  '              ColNumToCode(ColDestVTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt))
  'Next

End Sub
```

The only constants in “ModGlobal” that I believe need modification are `WshtDestName` and `WstSrcName`.  I have named the worksheets “Source” and “Destination”.  You need to change this.

Lastly, the routine `MergeTables` is in module ModMergeTables”:

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeTables()

  Dim Chr0 As String
  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim ColSrcFirst As Long
  Dim ColSrcLast As Long
  Dim ColSrcSecond As Long
  Dim IndicesCrnt() As Long
  Dim IndicesAll() As Long
  Dim InxInxCrnt As Long
  Dim InxInxCrntByTbl() As Long
  Dim InxTblCrnt As Long
  Dim KeyCrnt As String
  Dim KeyEmpty As String
  Dim KeysCrnt() As String
  Dim KeysAll() As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowDestCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long
  Dim SrcCellValues As Variant
  Dim StartTime As Single
  Dim WshtDest As Worksheet
  Dim WshtSrc As Worksheet

  StartTime = Timer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Load frmProgress
  With frmProgress
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Prepare to merge tables"
    .lblCountCrnt.Caption = ""
    .lblCountOf.Caption = ""
    .lblCountMax.Caption = ""
    .Show vbModeless
  End With
  DoEvents

  Set WshtSrc = Worksheets(WshtSrcName)
  Set WshtDest = Worksheets(WshtDestName)

  ' Load variables and arrays that provide easy access to the tables
  Call LoadTblVariables

  With WshtDest
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    ' Row 1: Spaces over H columns   "Table 1 over its V columns "   Ditto for Table 2 and Table 3
    For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
      Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, ColDestVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)), _
                       .Cells(1, ColDestVTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt)))
      Rng.Merge
      Rng.Value = "Table " & InxTblCrnt + 1
      Rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Next
  End With

  ' Row 2: H column headings   Table 1 V column headings   Ditto for table 2 and 3
  With WshtSrc
    ' H column headings
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, ColSrcHTblsStart(0)), _
                     .Cells(1, ColSrcHTblsEnd(0)))
    Rng.Copy Destination:=WshtDest.Cells(2, ColDestHTblStart)
    ' V column headings
    For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
      Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, ColSrcVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)), _
                       .Cells(1, ColSrcVTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt)))
      Rng.Copy Destination:=WshtDest.Cells(2, ColDestVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt))
    Next
  End With

  With frmProgress
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Copy source worksheet to an array"
    .lblCountCrnt.Caption = ""
    .lblCountOf.Caption = ""
    .lblCountMax.Caption = ""
  End With
  DoEvents

  Call FindLastRowCol(WshtSrc, RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast)

  With WshtSrc
    SrcCellValues = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowSrcLast, ColSrcLast)).Value
    ' SrcCellValues has the same structure and bounds as the worksheet
  End With

  'For RowSrcCrnt = 1 To RowSrcLast
  '  For ColSrcCrnt = 1 To ColSrcLast
  '    Debug.Print SrcCellValues(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcCrnt) & " ";
  '  Next
  '  Debug.Print
  'Next

  Chr0 = Chr$(0)
  ' Value of KeyCrnt if all the H columns are empty.
  KeyEmpty = String(ColSrcHTblsEnd(0) - ColSrcHTblsStart(0), Chr0)

  ReDim KeysAll(0 To InxTblMax, RowSrcDataFirst To RowSrcLast)
  ReDim IndicesAll(0 To InxTblMax, RowSrcDataFirst To RowSrcLast)

  For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax

    With frmProgress
      .lblMsg.Caption = "Build key and index arrays for table " & InxTblCrnt + 1
      .lblCountCrnt = 0
      .lblCountOf = "of"
      .lblCountMax = RowSrcLast
    End With
    DoEvents

    ReDim KeysCrnt(RowSrcDataFirst To RowSrcLast)
    ReDim IndicesCrnt(RowSrcDataFirst To RowSrcLast)

    ColSrcFirst = ColSrcHTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)
    ColSrcSecond = ColSrcFirst + 1
    ColSrcLast = ColSrcHTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt)

    For RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcDataFirst To RowSrcLast
      KeyCrnt = SrcCellValues(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcFirst)
      For ColSrcCrnt = ColSrcSecond To ColSrcLast
        ' Use of Chr0 (Chr$(0) as a separator ensures short fields come before
        ' long fields. For example, "ABC" & Chr0 comes before "ABCD" & Chr0
        KeyCrnt = KeyCrnt & Chr0 & SrcCellValues(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcCrnt)
      Next

      If KeyCrnt = KeyEmpty Then
        ' Make empty rows easy to identify
        KeysCrnt(RowSrcCrnt) = ""
      Else
        KeysCrnt(RowSrcCrnt) = KeyCrnt
      End If
      IndicesCrnt(RowSrcCrnt) = RowSrcCrnt

      frmProgress.lblCountCrnt = RowSrcCrnt
      DoEvents

    Next RowSrcCrnt

    'Debug.Print "Unsorted indices and keys for table " & InxTblCrnt + 1
    'For RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcDataFirst To RowSrcLast
    '  Debug.Print PadL(IndicesCrnt(RowSrcCrnt), 6) & " " & KeysCrnt(RowSrcCrnt)
    'Next

    With frmProgress
      .lblMsg.Caption = "Sort key and index array for table " & InxTblCrnt + 1
      .lblCountCrnt = ""
      .lblCountOf = ""
      .lblCountMax = ""
    End With
    DoEvents

    Call QuickSortC(IndicesCrnt, KeysCrnt)

    'Debug.Print "Sorted indices and keys for table " & InxTblCrnt + 1
    'For InxInxCrnt = RowSrcDataFirst To RowSrcLast
    '  RowSrcCrnt = IndicesCrnt(InxInxCrnt)
    '  Debug.Print PadL(RowSrcCrnt, 6) & " " & KeysCrnt(RowSrcCrnt)
    'Next

    ' KeysCrnt and IndicesCrnt are in the format required by QuickSortC.
    ' Move contents to KeysAll and IndicesAll ready for later stages

    With frmProgress
      .lblMsg.Caption = "Move key and index array for table " & InxTblCrnt + 1
      .lblCountCrnt = 0
      .lblCountOf = "of"
      .lblCountMax = RowSrcLast
    End With
    DoEvents

    For RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcDataFirst To RowSrcLast

      KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, RowSrcCrnt) = KeysCrnt(RowSrcCrnt)
      IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, RowSrcCrnt) = IndicesCrnt(RowSrcCrnt)

      frmProgress.lblCountCrnt = RowSrcCrnt
      DoEvents

    Next RowSrcCrnt

  Next InxTblCrnt

  'Debug.Print "Sorted keys and indices by table"
  'ReDim InxInxCrntByTbl(0 To InxTblCrnt)
  'For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
  '  ' Initialise InxInxCrntByTbl with row of first indexed key for each table.
  '  ' Note blank rows will have been sorted to top
  '  InxInxCrnt = RowSrcDataFirst
  '  Do While True
  '    If InxInxCrnt > RowSrcLast Then
  '      ' Should not be possible but table exhausted
  '      Exit Do
  '    End If
  '    RowSrcCrnt = IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt)
  '    If KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, RowSrcCrnt) <> "" Then
  '      ' Key found
  '      Exit Do
  '    End If
  '    InxInxCrnt = InxInxCrnt + 1
  '  Loop
  '  InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt) = InxInxCrnt
  'Next InxTblCrnt
  '
  '' Loop until all tables are exhausted
  'Do While True
  '  KeyCrnt = ""
  '  ' Find first table with an available key
  '  For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
  '   InxInxCrnt = InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt)
  '   If InxInxCrnt > RowSrcLast Then
  '     ' The table exhausted.  Try next.
  '   Else
  '     KeyCrnt = KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt))
  '     Exit For
  '   End If
  '  Next
  '  If KeyCrnt = "" Then
  '    ' All tables exhausted
  '    Exit Do
  '  End If
  '  ' Look for an earlier key in remaining tables
  '  For InxTblCrnt = InxTblCrnt + 1 To InxTblMax
  '   InxInxCrnt = InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt)
  '   If InxInxCrnt > RowSrcLast Then
  '     ' The table exhausted.  Try next.
  '   ElseIf KeyCrnt > KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt)) Then
  '     ' Earlier key found
  '     KeyCrnt = KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt))
  '   End If
  '  Next
  '  ' Have next key. Output row numbers for tables that contain this key
  '  Debug.Print KeyCrnt & "  ";
  '  For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
  '    InxInxCrnt = InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt)
  '    If InxInxCrnt > RowSrcLast Then
  '      ' The table exhausted so cannot contain this key.
  '      Debug.Print Space(7);
  '    ElseIf KeyCrnt = KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt)) Then
  '      ' This table contains current key
  '      Debug.Print PadL(IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt), 6) & " ";
  '      ' Step over used key ready for next loop
  '      InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt) = InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt) + 1
  '    Else
  '      ' This table not exhausted but does not contain this key
  '      Debug.Print Space(7);
  '    End If
  '  Next
  '  Debug.Print
  'Loop  ' until all tables are exhausted

  With frmProgress
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Build destination worksheet"
    .lblCountCrnt = 0
    .lblCountOf = "of"
    .lblCountMax = RowSrcLast
  End With
  DoEvents

  ReDim InxInxCrntByTbl(0 To InxTblCrnt)
  RowDestCrnt = RowDestDataFirst

  For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
    ' Initialise InxInxCrntByTbl with row of first indexed key for each table.
    ' Note blank rows will have been sorted to top
    InxInxCrnt = RowSrcDataFirst
    Do While True
      If InxInxCrnt > RowSrcLast Then
        ' Should not be possible but table exhausted
        Exit Do
      End If
      RowSrcCrnt = IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt)
      If KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, RowSrcCrnt) <> "" Then
        ' Key found
        Exit Do
      End If
      InxInxCrnt = InxInxCrnt + 1
    Loop
    InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt) = InxInxCrnt
  Next InxTblCrnt

  ' Loop until all tables are exhausted
  Do While True
    KeyCrnt = ""
    ' Find first table with an available key
    For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
     InxInxCrnt = InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt)
     If InxInxCrnt > RowSrcLast Then
       ' The table exhausted.  Try next.
     Else
       KeyCrnt = KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt))
       Exit For
     End If
    Next
    If KeyCrnt = "" Then
      ' All tables exhausted
      Exit Do
    End If
    ' Look for an earlier key in remaining tables
    For InxTblCrnt = InxTblCrnt + 1 To InxTblMax
     InxInxCrnt = InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt)
     If InxInxCrnt > RowSrcLast Then
       ' The table exhausted.  Try next.
     ElseIf KeyCrnt > KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt)) Then
       ' Earlier key found
       KeyCrnt = KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt))
     End If
    Next
    ' Have next key. Output row for this key
    ' Find first source table for this key
    For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
     InxInxCrnt = InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt)
     If InxInxCrnt > RowSrcLast Then
       ' The table exhausted.  Try next.
     Else
       RowSrcCrnt = IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt)
       If KeyCrnt = KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, RowSrcCrnt) Then
         Exit For
       End If
     End If
    Next
    ' Copy H columns to destination worksheet
    With WshtSrc
      Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcHTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)), _
                       .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcHTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt)))
    End With
    Rng.Copy WshtDest.Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestHTblStart)
    ' Copy V columns to destination worksheet
    Do While True
      With WshtSrc
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)), _
                         .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcVTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt)))
      End With
      Rng.Copy WshtDest.Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt))
      ' Step over used key ready for next loop
      InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt) = InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt) + 1
      InxTblCrnt = InxTblCrnt + 1
      If InxTblCrnt > InxTblMax Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      ' Find another table containing this key, if any
      Do While True
        InxInxCrnt = InxInxCrntByTbl(InxTblCrnt)
        If InxInxCrnt > RowSrcLast Then
          ' The table exhausted.  Try next if any.
        Else
          RowSrcCrnt = IndicesAll(InxTblCrnt, InxInxCrnt)
          If KeyCrnt = KeysAll(InxTblCrnt, RowSrcCrnt) Then
            'This table has V columns for this table
            Exit Do
          End If
        End If
        InxTblCrnt = InxTblCrnt + 1
        If InxTblCrnt > InxTblMax Then
          Exit Do
        End If
      Loop  ' until find another table for this key or no more tables
      If InxTblCrnt > InxTblMax Then
        Exit Do
      End If

    Loop  ' until no more tables for this row

    RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1

    frmProgress.lblCountCrnt = InxInxCrntByTbl(0)
    DoEvents

  Loop  ' until all tables exhausted

    With frmProgress
      .lblMsg.Caption = "Finalise destination worksheet"
      .lblCountCrnt.Caption = ""
      .lblCountOf.Caption = ""
      .lblCountMax.Caption = ""
    End With
    DoEvents

  With WshtDest
    ' Colour V columns
    For InxTblCrnt = 0 To InxTblMax
      Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, ColDestVTblsStart(InxTblCrnt)), _
                       .Cells(1, ColDestVTblsEnd(InxTblCrnt))).EntireColumn
      Rng.Interior.Color = ClrVTbls(InxTblCrnt)
    Next
    ' Adjust column widths
    .Columns.AutoFit
  End With

  Unload frmProgress

  Debug.Print "Tables merged in " & Timer - StartTime & " seconds"

End Sub
```

I have retained all the diagnostic code I used during development but have commented it out.  You may find it helpful to uncomment this diagnostic code and work through the code studying how it works.  This will be essential if my data does not match yours and you have to study why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 2. Part 1**

Answer 2 exceeds Stack Overflow’s character limit so I have had to divide it into two.

Do not worry too much about your “sloppy” code.  None of were born knowing VBA.  Although the basic language is simple, the hundreds of libraries adding functionality are not.  Perhaps worse, there are often several approaches to achieving the same effect.  For your own code, you can pick your favourite but, if you look at or borrow from other people’s code, you need to be familiar with every approach.  It takes lots of practice to become good at VBA and, in my experience, there is always something more to learn.

This is a completely new answer.  Please study the original answer, if you have not done so, because it contains a detailed review of the first part of your code which I believe you will find helpful.

My major criticism of your code is lack of design.  You start by moving table 1 to the destination worksheet which is easy.  You then compare every row in table 1 with every row in table 2.  Each comparison requires four Ifs.  That is four, million, million Ifs before any other code is considered.  I have never attempted to time individual VBA statement so I will assume an If takes one millionth of a second although this seems very optimistic.  If this assumption is true, merging tables 1 and 2 would take 46 days just for the Ifs.  Merging table 1 and 3 would then take another 46 days.

The first approach I considered was to sort the three tables into one.  I quickly abandoned that approach because Excel does not support worksheets with three million rows.

The next approach I considered was to sort the three tables separately into ascending order.  I would then work down the tables looking for the lowest key, move the rows from each table for that key to the destination worksheet and loop looking for the next lowest key.  I planned to use Excel’s sort because I thought that would be easier for you to understand.  I developed this approach some way before remembering a fatal flaw.  The If comparison is strictly Unicode but the Excel sort is not.  If your values are strictly alphabetic or strictly numeric, Excel will sort as you might expect.  But mix alphabetic and numeric values or include punctuation and the Excel sort becomes eccentric.  You can use the Excel sort or you can use If but you cannot use both on the same data.

I have a VBA Quick Sort routine which I use when strict Unicode is required.  I will not say more about this routine because I believe it is adequately documented.  Switching to my sort routine instead of Excel’s was not difficult but I should have stopped to rethink when my design hit a problem.  My routine is limited only by memory and it should be able to sort three million rows.  I should have reconsidered my original approach.  I have never tried merging three tables and it was much more complicated than merging two.  Reverting to approach 1 is one of the alternative ideas I will try.

I hope that is enough background on my approach but come back with questions if necessary.

I dislike routines that say “This may take from a few minutes to several hours” and then go quiet until they finish so I have implemented a progress form.  I cannot post a form so you will have to create it yourself.  This is my form:

[image: Progress form]

The exact layout is not important.  The form is named “frmProgress” and has a caption “Progress merging tables.”   There are four controls which are all labels.  This form is strictly for the macro to report progress, there are no input controls.  From top to bottom, left to right the controls are “lblMsg”, “lblCountCrnt”, “lblCountOf” and “lblCountMax”.  The captions in my form are just to aid form design, they are all overwritten at runtime.  The text in “lblCountMax” is left aligned but this is not required.  If you have never created a userform, searching for “VBA create userform” brings up lots of tutorials.

It would be possible to include all the code below in a single module.  However, I prefer to divide my code so there is one module per purpose.

Over the years I have created standard subroutines and functions that perform tasks I need again and again.  I use Excel’s Personal workbook as a library so they are accessible from every one of my workbooks.

This module I name “LibOffice” and it contains routines useful across Office:

```
Option Explicit
Function Median3(ByRef Indices() As Long, Keys() As String, _
                 ByVal InxLow As Long, ByVal InxHigh As Long) As Long

  ' In QuickSortA, the pivot would be the first or last
  ' value in the partition.  This gave good results unless the array
  ' was already sorted or reserve sorted.
  ' Selecting the mediam of the low, high and mid-value significantly
  ' reduced the duration of the sort in this situation.

  Dim InxIS As Long
  Dim IndicesSelected(1 To 3) As Long
  Dim IndexSave As Long

  If InxLow + 1 = InxHigh Then
    ' No mid-value.
    'Debug.Assert False
    Median3 = InxHigh
    Exit Function
  End If

  IndicesSelected(1) = InxLow
  IndicesSelected(2) = (InxLow + InxHigh) \ 2
  IndicesSelected(3) = InxHigh

  ' Sort elements of IndicesSelected into ascending value of referenced key
  InxIS = 1
  Do While InxIS < 3
    If Keys(Indices(IndicesSelected(InxIS))) > Keys(Indices(IndicesSelected(InxIS + 1))) Then
      ' Swap out of sequence entries
      'Debug.Assert False
      IndexSave = IndicesSelected(InxIS)
      IndicesSelected(InxIS) = IndicesSelected(InxIS + 1)
      IndicesSelected(InxIS + 1) = IndexSave
      If InxIS > 1 Then
        ' There is a previous entry so check entry
        ' moved back does not need to be moved further
        'Debug.Assert False
        InxIS = InxIS - 1
      Else
        ' At beginning of array so check next pair
        'Debug.Assert False
        InxIS = InxIS + 1
      End If
    Else
      ' This pair in correct sequence so check next pair.
      InxIS = InxIS + 1
    End If
  Loop

  Median3 = IndicesSelected(2)

End Function
Public Function PadL(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with leading PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Sep15 Coded
  ' 20Dec15 Added code so overlength strings are not truncated
  ' 10Jun16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadL = Str
  Else
    PadL = Right$(String(PadLen, PadChr) & Str, PadLen)
  End If

End Function
Public Function PadR(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with trailing PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Nov15 Coded
  ' 15Sep16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadR = Str
  Else
    PadR = Left$(Str & String(PadLen, PadChr), PadLen)
  End If

End Function
Public Sub QuickSortC(ByRef Indices() As Long, ByRef Keys() As String)

  ' * On entry, Keys() contains the values by which the target array is to be sorted.
  ' * On entry, Indices(N) identifies the position within the target array of the
  '   entry represented by Keys(N).
  ' * On exit, Indices() will have been sorted so it references the entries in the target
  '   array in ascending sequence. That is, Indices(LBound(Indices)) is the first entry in
  '   the target array, Indices(LBound(Indices)+1) is the second entry in the target array
  '   and so on.  If descending sequence is required, read Indices in reverse sequence.
  ' * The "target array" can be an array, a collection, part of a worksheet or anything
  '   that has a sequence.  The values of the target array could be simple data types
  '   (long, string, etc) or user data types or objects.  The only restriction is that
  '   the value or part of the value of each element is, or can be converted to, a
  '   string whose value can be placed in Keys().  The values in Keys() and Indices()
  '   could represent the entire array, a range or a selection of elements.  It is the
  '   caller's responsibility to create Keys() and Indices() as required so QuickSort can
  '   create the desired sequence.

  ' * In Mar 2007, or perhaps earlier, I coded an implementation of the Shell Sort.
  '   That macro had the comparisons controlling the sort hard coded into the routine.
  '   Over time, I created versions to sort strings, numbers of various types and
  '   two-dimensional arrays. This was neither convenient nor efficient.
  ' * Other languages provide a simple interface to a consistent sort routine that
  '   allow different sort sequences of different data types. I wanted some of that
  '   convenience with a VBA sort.  I also wanted an implementation of Quick Sort which
  '   in most situations is faster than Shell Sort.
  ' * VBA versions of Quick Sort are available on the web but I could not find any
  '   that had the functionality I sought.
  ' * Passing the name of a comparison macro to QuickSort as a parameter and using
  '   Application.Run gave me the functionality I sought but was impossibly slow.
  ' * I tried other approaches which gave me the performation I wanted but not the
  '   the functional. Eventually I settled for making the caller responsible for
  '   creating Indices and Keys. Thid gave me good performation plus an approximation
  '   of the functionality I sought.

  ' Coded 2014 - 2016  No details recorded although I recall a lot of experimentation
  '                    with different techniques before settling for an index sort and
  '                    then discovery of an obscure error in the initial
  '                    implementation of the quick sort algorithm

  ' The arrays Indices and Keys must match.
  Debug.Assert LBound(Indices) = LBound(Keys)
  Debug.Assert UBound(Indices) = UBound(Keys)

  Dim InxHigh As Long        ' End of current partition
  Dim InxHighCrnt As Long    ' Search from end of partition for key that belongs after pivot
  Dim InxHighPrev            ' Value after previous swap
  Dim InxLow As Long         ' Start of current partition
  Dim InxLowCrnt As Long
  Dim InxLowPrev             ' Value after previous swap
  Dim InxPivot As Long       ' Search from start of partition for key that belongs before pivot
  Dim InxTemp As Long
  Dim Pivot As String
  Dim ToDoHigh As New Collection  '\ ToDoLow(N) to ToDoHigh(N) identifies
  Dim ToDoLow As New Collection   '/ a range to be partitioned.

  ToDoLow.Add LBound(Indices)
  ToDoHigh.Add UBound(Indices)

  ' Loop until every range to be partitioned has been extracted from ToDoLow
  ' and ToDoHigh and processed
  Do While ToDoLow.Count > 0

    ' Extract and remove next range to partition from collections ToDoLow and ToDoHigh
    InxLow = ToDoLow(ToDoLow.Count)
    InxHigh = ToDoHigh(ToDoHigh.Count)
    ToDoLow.Remove (ToDoLow.Count)
    ToDoHigh.Remove (ToDoHigh.Count)

    ' Initialise control indices
    InxPivot = Median3(Indices, Keys, InxLow, InxHigh)
    InxLowCrnt = InxLow - 1
    InxHighCrnt = InxHigh + 1

    Pivot = Keys(Indices(InxPivot))

    Do ' Until Index for searching from start crosses index searching from end

      Do ' Until find next element from start that belongs after Pivot
        InxLowCrnt = InxLowCrnt + 1
        If Pivot < Keys(Indices(InxLowCrnt)) Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If InxLowCrnt = InxHigh Then
          Exit Do
        End If
      Loop

      Do  ' Until find next element from end that belongs before Pivot
        InxHighCrnt = InxHighCrnt - 1
        If Keys(Indices(InxHighCrnt)) < Pivot Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If InxHighCrnt = InxLow Then
          Exit Do
        End If
      Loop

     If InxLowCrnt < InxHighCrnt Then
      ' Swap elements
      InxTemp = Indices(InxLowCrnt)
      Indices(InxLowCrnt) = Indices(InxHighCrnt)
      Indices(InxHighCrnt) = InxTemp
      InxLowPrev = InxLowCrnt
      InxHighPrev = InxHighCrnt
     End If

    Loop Until InxHighCrnt <= InxLowCrnt

    ' Final tidy.  Move pivot to its final position by swapping with last low or high
    If InxPivot < InxLowCrnt And InxPivot > InxHighCrnt Then
      ' Pivot is between InxLowCrnt and InxHighCrnt so is already in its final position
      ' Validate pivot it correctly positioned
      'If InxPivot > InxLow Then
      '  Debug.Assert Keys(Indices(InxPivot - 1)) <= Keys(Indices(InxPivot))
      'End If
      'If InxPivot < InxLow Then
      '  Debug.Assert Keys(Indices(InxPivot)) <= Keys(Indices(InxPivot + 1))
      'End If
    ElseIf InxPivot < InxLowCrnt Then
      ' Pivot is within the low half of the partition.
      ' InxHighCrnt is the highest entry with a value less than the pivot so swap
      ' pivot with it.
      Debug.Assert InxHighCrnt >= InxLow  ' Don't think InxHighCrnt can be below InxLow but check
      InxTemp = Indices(InxHighCrnt)
      Indices(InxHighCrnt) = Indices(InxPivot)
      Indices(InxPivot) = InxTemp
      InxPivot = InxHighCrnt   ' New position of pivot
      ' Validate pivot it correctly positioned
      'If InxPivot > InxLow Then
      '  Debug.Assert Keys(Indices(InxPivot - 1)) <= Keys(Indices(InxPivot))
      'End If
      'If InxPivot < InxLow Then
      '  Debug.Assert Keys(Indices(InxPivot)) <= Keys(Indices(InxPivot + 1))
      'End If
    Else
      ' Pivot is within the high half of the partition.
      ' InxLowCrnt is the lowest entry with a value greater than the pivot so swap
      ' pivot with it.
      Debug.Assert InxLowCrnt <= InxHigh  ' Don't think InxLowCrnt can be above InxHigh but check
      InxTemp = Indices(InxLowCrnt)
      Indices(InxLowCrnt) = Indices(InxPivot)
      Indices(InxPivot) = InxTemp
      InxPivot = InxLowCrnt   ' New position of pivot
      ' Validate pivot it correctly positioned
      'If InxPivot > InxLow Then
      '  Debug.Assert Keys(Indices(InxPivot - 1)) <= Keys(Indices(InxPivot))
      'End If
      'If InxPivot < InxLow Then
      '  Debug.Assert Keys(Indices(InxPivot)) <= Keys(Indices(InxPivot + 1))
      'End If
    End If

    ' The original algorithm used recursion. For VBA, the use
    ' of two collections is of the order of twice as fast.
    If InxPivot - 1 > InxLow Then
      ToDoLow.Add InxLow
      ToDoHigh.Add InxPivot - 1
    End If
    If InxHigh > InxPivot + 1 Then
      ToDoLow.Add InxPivot + 1
      ToDoHigh.Add InxHigh
     End If

  Loop  ' Until ToDoLow and ToDoHigh are empty

End Sub
```

This module I name “LibExcel” and contains routines useful for Excel:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim ColCode As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  ' 3Feb12  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  ' ??????  Renamed from ColCode to create a more helpful name

  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    ColCode = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      ColCode = Chr(65 + PartNum) & ColCode
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = ColCode

End Function
Public Sub FindLastRowCol(ByRef Wsht As Worksheet, ByRef RowLast As Long, _
                          ByRef ColLast As Long)

  ' Sets RowLast and ColLast to the last row and column with a value
  ' in worksheet Wsht

  ' The motivation for coding this routine was the discovery that Find by
  ' previous row found a cell formatted as Merge and Center but Find by
  ' previous column did not. I had known that Find would miss merged
  ' cells but this was new to me.

  '   Dec16  Coded
  ' 31Dec16  Corrected handling of UserRange
  ' 15Feb17  SpecialCells was giving a higher row number than Find for
  '          no reason I could determine.  Added code to check for a
  '          value on rows and columns above those returned by Find
  ' 25Jun17  Found column with value above that found by Find. Fixed.

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLastFind As Long
  Dim ColLastOther As Long
  Dim ColLastTemp As Long
  Dim ColLeft As Long
  Dim ColRight As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowIncludesMerged As Boolean
  Dim RowBot As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLastFind As Long
  Dim RowLastOther As Long
  Dim RowLastTemp As Long
  Dim RowTop As Long

  With Wsht

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastFind = 0
      ColLastFind = 0
    Else
      RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      ColLastFind = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Else
      If RowLastFind < Rng.Row Then
        RowLastFind = Rng.Row
      End If
      If ColLastFind < Rng.Column Then
        ColLastFind = Rng.Column
      End If
    End If

    Set Rng = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      RowLastOther = 0
      ColLastOther = 0
    Else
      RowLastOther = Rng.Row
      ColLastOther = Rng.Column
    End If

    Set Rng = .UsedRange
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Else
      If RowLastOther < Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        RowLastOther = Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
      End If
      If ColLastOther < Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1 Then
        ColLastOther = Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
      End If
    End If

    If RowLastFind < RowLastOther Then
      ' Higher row found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While RowLastOther > RowLastFind
        ColLastTemp = .Cells(RowLastOther, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If ColLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(RowLastOther, 1).Value <> "" Then
          Debug.Assert False
          ' Is this possible
          ' Row after RowLastFind has value
          RowLastFind = RowLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        RowLastOther = RowLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf RowLastFind > RowLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    RowLast = RowLastFind

    If ColLastFind < ColLastOther Then
      ' Higher column found by SpecialCells or UserRange
      Do While ColLastOther > ColLastFind
        RowLastTemp = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColLastOther).End(xlUp).Row
        If RowLastTemp > 1 Or .Cells(1, ColLastOther).Value <> "" Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          ' Column after ColLastFind has value
          ' Possible causes:
          '   * Find does not recognise merged cells
          '   ' Find does not examine hidden cells
          ColLastFind = ColLastOther
          Exit Do
        End If
        ColLastOther = ColLastOther - 1
      Loop
    ElseIf ColLastFind > ColLastOther Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Is this possible
    End If
    ColLast = ColLastFind

  End With

End Sub
```